# Menu drop dentro de frame sobre outro frame

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Ola, como faço para meu menu que esta dentro de um frame passar por cima de um outro frame? Tenho o seguinte html:

```
<frameset rows="150,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="menu" src="Menu.aspx" noresize scrolling="no" />
    <frame name="sistemas" src="TelaInterna.aspx" noresize />
</frameset>
```

No primeiro frame tenho um menu, mas quando dou o hover em um dos itens e a menu exibe os itens internos, ao invés do drop descer ele sobe, pois não acha espaço no frame. Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de dizer que o frame 1 exibirá o conteúdo sobrepondo o do frame 2, ou seja, mais próximo da tela.

Obs: entendo que trabalhar com frames é um problema e limitante, mas neste caso preciso encontrar uma forma de fazer isso sem remover a estrutura de frames. Este é o único requisito pois o projeto tem essa restrição :(.

Comment: até encontrei um forma de fazer um cross frame via javascript mas achei a solução "desagradável" pois a forma de montar os links do menu é complexa(http://deluxe-menu.com/cross-frame-mode-sample.html). Me parece que não tem como resolver mesmo de forma simples com alguma mudança de html ou css apenas. :/

Comment: nao tem como vc tera que aumentar a frame de acordo com o tamanho de sua lista

Comment: verdade @joao, tive que mudar a abordagem e buscar outro caminho, este se mostrou impraticável. obrigado.